# Temperature sensors doesn't show two of my cores

Tags: temperature, sensors

I installed sensors, but this don't show me the 4 temperatures of my 4 cores, I have a Intel Core i5,

```
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +26.8°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
temp2:         +0.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +40.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:       +47.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

I followed the same procedure in other i5 machine, and sensors show me the 4 temperatures of the 4 cores, I installed: apt-get install lm-sensors, apt-get install hddtemp, sensors-detect, modprobe coretemp (in my case).

Why I can't see the other 2 cores' temperatures

What is temp1, temp2, coretemp-isa-0000, Adapter: ISA adapter

I saw in other forums that sensors show a lot of temperatures, How I can do that?, What other program I have to install?

Comment: What is the exact model of your processor? It may only have 2 physical cores (and hyperthreading).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is a different i5 CPU (Some are manufactured with 2 physical cores, some with 4, and some have HT enabled, which double the number of cores which the os sees. Check wiki [Core i5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i5) and
run this `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

This will show more info about your cpu.

Comment: But in my System Monitor, it show 4 CPUs, I chek /proc/cpuinfo and it show 4 processors.

Comment: We've got a new i3 computer at the dormitory, it clearly has two cores. So I tried the `cat /proc/cpuinfo`, and it showed 4 cores. The `cpufreq-info` also showed 4 cores. `htop` showed 4 cores, but the `sensors` command showed only two temperatures. According to wikipedia, i3 is only manufactured with 2 cores. The other two are virtual cores. The OS sees 4 identical cores. Your configuration looks the same, you also have two physical cores and two virtual cores. There is no problem. The other machine has 4 physical cores. How you can measure a temperature, if a core physically doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

Use CPU Frequency Scaling Monitoring applet in panel, just add it to panel.

[image: add to panel picture]

After add to panel, you can edit the

Use Hardware Sensors Monitoring applet in panel.
[image: Hardware Sensors Monitoring]`Preferences` to choose which CPU to monitor.

edit the `Preferences` to choose which CPU to monitor.
[image: choose CPU]

Comment: Thanks but I don't want an applet, I use conky, only I want that sensors show me all temperatures.